# UserAuth type in ServiceStack

Tags: authentication, servicestack, api-key

I don't understand:

**1)** Why the field "UserAuthId" in the Table "ApiKey" is of type **varchar** and, in the other tables, is of type **int**.

I'd like to create a relation between UserAut table and ApiKey like that I did between *UserAuth=>UserAuthRole*  and  *UserAuth=>UserAuthDetails*

**2)** Why the field UserAuthId in the ApiKey table is nullable.

**3)** Why the fields RefId and RefIdStr are placed in every table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserAuth` Table used by the RDBMS Auth Repository has an `int` primary key but the [AuthUserSession has a string UserAuthId](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/41352c10c44df29d1fbde368bd0d56095560e210/src/ServiceStack/AuthUserSession.cs#L20) as it can be populated from other data sources using different data types for their Primary Key. The `ApiKeyAuthProvider` ApiKey table has to be able to work with alternative sources so uses a string `UserAuthId` as well.

The `RefId` and `RefIdStr` fields are an [extensibility option for extending UserAuth tables](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#extending-userauth-tables) which you can use to add a reference your own tables.